# Yellow box showing Toggles Button

Tags: javascript

Hello I'm Yellow Box Showing in the Web-page and it takes full page how to reduce the size of the yellow box

```
<button class="sign-in-form__password-visibility-toggle-button" aria-label="Show your explain password" data-tracking-control-name="homepage-basic_sign in-form_password-visibility-toggle-button" type="button" on-click="toggle(this)">Show</button>
```

Comment: can i look at the css styles code?

Comment: button {   
       background: #0073b1;   
       width: 100%;  
        color: white;   
        padding: 0 32px;
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        transition-duration: 167ms;   
        margin: 10px 0px;   
        border: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        color: #fff;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 2rem;
        font-family: inherit;
        line-height: 48px;
        overflow: hidden;
        outline-width: 2px;
        cursor: pointer;
        }

Comment: just change `width` attribute to `20%` for ex.